# Basic storage of jquery checkbox values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do something which I think should be pretty basic but I just can't seem to find an answer that makes sense to my basic understanding of jquery.

**Question 1:**

I'm trying to generate a checkbox input that returns a value of 0 if left unchecked and returns a value of 1 if checked.

Here's how I figure I'd generate the checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner/>
```

Here's how I figure I'd send the value:

```
item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("value",p.owner);
```

**Question 2:**

How would I retrieve the value, once saved to my database, and tell my checkbox to display accordingly?

Here's vaguely how I figure it would work:

```
owner: $("#dialog input[name=owner]").attr("value"),
```

Where owner is the field name being sent retrieved from the database via php.

Anyway, this question has been the bane of my existence for a duration that's slightly embarrassing.  An explanation of this would be greatly appreciated, as I've apparently been having a hard time connecting the dots on this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use the standard `true` and `false` for checkboxes? You can store boolean in a DB.

Comment: Are you using PHP server-side, then? You mention it but didn't tag the question with it.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for the clarification; yes I am using php server-side.  Think it's important enough to tag?

Comment: Since it can affect the answers you get, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:
1. In HTML make one input:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner' value="1" />
```

and in PHP make check:

```
if (!isset($_POST['owner'])) {
  $_POST['owner'] = 0;
}
```

2. In HTML make just two inputs in exactly this order:

```
<input type='hidden' name='owner' value="0" />
<input type='checkbox' id='part_owner' name='owner' value="1" />
```

If checkbox will be checked, form will send value 1. Otherwise 0 will be sent.

When you use jQuery, you can detect if input is checked by:

```
if ($('#part_owner').is(':checked')) ...
```

Or check it with:

```
$('#part_owner').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: For the first option, I'm running into the situation that 1 is returned, regardless of whether it's selected or not.  And in situation 2, it seems that adding the hidden input crashes the script.

Comment: If you do in jQuery $('#part_owner').val(), then it always returns you input's value (both when it is checked or not). You have to use $('#part_owner').is(':checked').

Comment: If you want to do everything in Javascript, use 3 last rows from my answer.

Comment: Ok, this is almost starting to make some sense to me.  However, I don't see anything in my code that looks like .val().  Am I implicitly using it?  [Here's a .txt of my javascript if you'd like a look.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/People_java.txt)  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: $(...).attr('value') is same as $(...).val().

Comment: Got it!  So far so good; that seems to be saving properly.  Now I'm trying to resolve "Question 2" from my post (checking/not checking the box depending on the previously saved value).  How might I go about doing that?

Comment: If value should be checked, use $('#part_owner').attr('checked', true). If unchecked - $('#part_owner').removeAttr('checked');

Comment: Like a charm!  I just tacked this on: `if(p.owner == 1) {item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("checked",true);} else {item.find("input[name=owner]").attr("checked",false);}`  Thanks for holding my hand through figuring it out; I'll get this stuff sooner or later!  :-)